# mysql_real_escape_string before mysql_real_query

Tags: mysql, c, api

I'm storing the hash signature of my users certificates in MySQL to do an post handshake verification. `X509_digest()` generates a 20 byte (SHA1) hash that may contain null byte and I'm comparing it to the database hash that is stored in a `BINARY(20)` column. My question is: if the `mysql_real_escape_string()` deal with the null byte and other MySQL special characters, why should I use the `mysql_real_query()` instead of `mysql_query()` as shown in every examples? Remember that I'm escaping the hash before include it into the query string, so there is no null byte, special character or misleading backslash that generates an wrong `strlen()` output.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you specify exactly which examples you're looking at?

Comment: @jbafford http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlc/ etc

Answer (score 1):

The [`mysql_query`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-query.html) and [`mysql_real_query`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-real-query.html) documentation indicates that the difference between the two is that `mysql_real_query` takes a string and a length; and `mysql_query` takes only a string (and thus requires performing a `strlen` to get the length).

This is even more clear in the actual source code:

```
// From libmysql/libmysql.c
int STDCALL
mysql_query(MYSQL *mysql, const char *query)
{
  return mysql_real_query(mysql,query, (ulong) strlen(query));
}
```

`mysql_query` is literally a thin wrapper around `mysql_real_query`, and if you can call `mysql_real_query` directly, you should.

Comment: Thanks, but that is not all. The `mysql_real_escape_string()` will not generate output that contains any byte that will compromise the `strlen()`, even if I don't use it, since the `mysql_query()` does?

Comment: It's not so much that `mysql_real_escape_string` does or does not provide strings with escaped nulls; it's that there's a real cost to calling `strlen`, and if you don't have to, then you shouldn't. In the examples, it has enough information to get the string length without requiring a call to strlen, so regardless of the contents being safe, it calls `mysql_real_query` directly because it can, and because it's faster.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of it. Can you tell me how the usage of two `stpcpy()` calls is faster than the a single `strlen()`? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html

Comment: `my_stpcpy` returns a pointer to the new closing NUL. When that return value is passed to `mres`, `mres`essentially appends its output onto the buffer. `end += mres(...)` updates `end` to point to the new NUL (`mres` returns a length), so when fed back in, the next `my_strcpy` is used as a string append. The only thing that's *actually* being copied is the constant strings in the `my_stpcpy` calls. The `my_stpcpy` calls *have to* happen to properly build the query string. But as an intentional side effect of `my_stpcpy`'s implementation, an expensive call to `strlen` can be avoided.

Comment: Sure, but both functions loops until reach a NULL byte. The `strcpy()` function uses `for()` and `strlen()` uses `while()`. So, I'm still trying to understand how `strcpy()` is faster...

Comment: There is *no* call to `strcpy` anywhere in that code. Between the `my_stpcpy`s and `mres`s *all* appending onto the buffer, the string length is evident from the final result. All the calls to `my_stpcpy` and `mres` *have to happen* in order to build up the query string. Collectively, they iterate over the entire built query *exactly* once. (Those calls are *appending* the destination buffer; they're not copying the destination buffer each time.) At the end, the length is apparent, and a further call to `strlen` is not necessary.